# How to get selected item of spinner from an intent

Tags: android, spinner

I'm using a spinner filled with an array of values from one activity.
I'm having problems getting the value for a different spinner on another activity.
How can i use it on intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the value of the spinner you want in different activity through intent bundle. Try this is the activity from where you want data :

```
Intent asd = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
asd.putExtras("Your Key", "Your Spinner Value");
startActivity(asd);
```

And to get the value :

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtras("Your Key");
```